Product of a sequence of matrices chosen from a set of two matrices
Consider two 2-by-2 real matrices $A_0$ and $A_1$ which satisfy $A_0 A_0^T +A_1 A_1^T = I$. A probability distribution is defined by
$$
P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)= \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}(A_{x_1} A_{x_2} A_{x_3}\cdots A_{x_n} A_{x_n}^T A_{x_{n-1}}^T A_{x_{n-2}}^T \cdots A_{x_1}^T).
$$
When $A_0$ and $A_1$ commute with each other, $P$ is clearly a mixture of two binomial distributions. My question is, in general when $n$ is large, is there anything we can say about this probability distribution when $A_0$ does not commute with $A_1$, e.g. the concentration properties?
